Past Perfect or Simple Past When Using Since in Reported Speech?
While reading The Beautiful and Damned, I stumbled upon a passage that caught my attention. It stated,

Only with the flow through the transmitter of his own familiar but faintly impersonal tone did she realize that it had been three years since they had met.

My question is, would it have been grammatical to write that sentence fragment as "It had been three years since they met?" That would be how I would have written the sentence had I been in Fitzgerald's place, but I'm no writer of his caliber, although I do want to know which version is the grammatical one.

From the context it's clear that "She realized after the meet and hence the pluperfect. But it's ok to dispense with had met and still have a grammatical sentence. The issue isn't really about grammar.

Yes, but suppose she herself were speaking to the person about how much time has passed since they last met. She might say, "it's been three years since we met." This makes sense to me because "it's been" is in the present perfect, and "met" is in the simple past, thus clarifying the chronological order of events. But in "it had been three years since they had met," both "had been" and "had met" are in the past perfect. The chronological order here seems less clear to me. I, however, may be wrong, so feel free to point it out to me!

I think you're right. In this example, you couldn't write it like "It's been three years since we have met". You have to use simple past. But in the Fitzgerald example, either works although I might prefer the simple past. I think it boils to a stylistic choice rather than grammar.

Since is most natural with past perfect or simple past. That may not seem very logical, but that's the way it is.

Today, we wouldn't say we needed "had been" and "had met." Setting one verb with "had" places it further in the past than the other. Now each is earlier? Or both earlier than "realize"?
